# BeautifulSoup exclude a tag in findAll

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, lxml

In beautifulsoup how can we exclude a tag within particular tag while using findAll.

Let us consider this example, I want to find all the `<p>` tags in the html except the

tags within `<tr>` tag.

```
soup.findAll(['p'])
```

The above code will fetch all the `<p>` tags but I need to exculde the `<p>` tags within `<tr>` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to select all `p` that doesn't have `tr` as parent in any level.

You can select all `p` then filter the results using `findParent` function. `findParent` will return the first parent with a given tag name otherwise `None`.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
  <tr>
    <p>1</p>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p>2</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  
  <p>3</p>
  
  <div>
    <p>4</p>
  </div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
print([p for p in soup.findAll('p') if not p.findParent('tr')])
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `.select`. Examples: 
Select all  `<p>` tags but exclude the `<p>` tags within `<tr>` tag.

```
soup.select('p:not(tr > p)')
```

Select all `<p>`tags but exclude the `<p>`tags that are a child of `<tr>` tag

```
soup.select('p:not(tr p)')
```

Select all `<p>` and `<h2>`tags but exclude the `<p>`tags that are a child of `<tr>` tag

```
soup.select('p,h2:not(tr p)')
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What can I do I need to use multiple selectors? For example I need to use both P and h2 tag.

Comment: You just add a comma. I have added an example for that too.

Comment: Can you add html example?